# how to split a string in python using DF.split

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, split

Sorry if this question has been already asked. I cant seem to find the answer on internet.

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
Positions=pd.DataFrame( {'position':rateQualityOutTrim['position'].unique() })
    Positions
                    position
0       CITI_52299G66_201210
1       CITI_52299G66_201210
2       CITI_52299G66_202374
3       CITI_52299G66_202734
4       CITI_52299G66_204130
5       CITI_52299G66_204685
6       CITI_52299G66_205140
7       CITI_52299G66_206425

new=Positions['position'].str.split(pat="_", n=2, expand=False)

new
0         [CITI, 52299G66, 201210]
1         [CITI, 52299G66, 201210]
2         [CITI, 52299G66, 202374]
3         [CITI, 52299G66, 202734]
4         [CITI, 52299G66, 204130]
5         [CITI, 52299G66, 204685]
```

I am looking to extract each element separately.

I have used this:

```
Positions.position.apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[0])
0         CITI
1         CITI
2         CITI
3         CITI

Positions.position.apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1])
0        201210     
1        201210
2        202374
3        202734
4        204130
5        204685
```

The middle element i struggle to extract it. Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: `Positions['position'].str.split("_").str[1]` ?

Comment: it did not work  iam afraid it says "list index out of range"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indexing by [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df=Positions['position'].str.split(pat="_")
print (df)

0    [CITI, 52299G66, 201210]
1    [CITI, 52299G66, 201210]
2    [CITI, 52299G66, 202374]
3    [CITI, 52299G66, 202734]
4    [CITI, 52299G66, 204130]
5    [CITI, 52299G66, 204685]
6    [CITI, 52299G66, 205140]
7    [CITI, 52299G66, 206425]
Name: position, dtype: object

print (df.str[0])
print (df.str[1])
print (df.str[2])
```

Or create new DataFrame:

```
df = Positions['position'].str.split(pat="_", expand=True)
print (df)
      0         1       2
0  CITI  52299G66  201210
1  CITI  52299G66  201210
2  CITI  52299G66  202374
3  CITI  52299G66  202734
4  CITI  52299G66  204130
5  CITI  52299G66  204685
6  CITI  52299G66  205140
7  CITI  52299G66  206425
```

And if necessary select each column:

```
print (df[0])
print (df[1])
print (df[2])
```

Comment: Creating a new DF is even better. Thank you so much   ... PS: it seems that fourth column has been created with 'None'?  1       CITI  52299G66  201210  None
  `2       CITI  52299G66  202374  None
3       CITI  52299G66  202734  None
4       CITI  52299G66  204130  None
5       CITI  52299G66  204685  None
6       CITI  52299G66  205140  None`

Comment: @SBad - hmm, maybe in some data are `3` times `_`

Comment: Sure i ll check that  but regardless your proposition works fine. Thank you Sir!